# Display custom post type from dynamic custom field

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query-posts, post-meta

I am trying to create a custom meta box that lets you add rows dynamically. Following code snippet works fine and and saves data in my edit page section. However, I can't get it to display the data on the actual page:

```
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'dynamic_add_custom_box' );

    /* Do something with the data entered */
    add_action( 'save_post', 'dynamic_save_postdata' );

    /* Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens */
    function dynamic_add_custom_box() {
        add_meta_box(
            'dynamic_sectionid',
    __( 'My Tracks', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
    'dynamic_inner_custom_box',
    'page');
    }

    /* Prints the box content */
     function dynamic_inner_custom_box() {
        global $post;
        // Use nonce for verification
        wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'dynamicMeta_noncename' );
?>
<div id="meta_inner">
<?php

//get the saved meta as an arry
$songs = get_post_meta($post->ID,'songs',true);

$c = 0;
if ( count( $songs ) > 0 ) {
    foreach( $songs as $track ) {
        if ( isset( $track['title'] ) || isset( $track['track'] ) ) {
            printf( '<p>Song Title <input type="text" name="songs[%1$s][title]" value="%2$s" /> -- Track number : <input type="text" name="songs[%1$s][track]" value="%3$s" /><span class="remove">%4$s</span></p>', $c, $track['title'], $track['track'], __( 'Remove Track' ) );
            $c = $c +1;
        }
    }
}

        ?>
    <span id="here"></span>
    <span class="add"><?php _e('Add Tracks'); ?></span>
    <script>
        var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var count = <?php echo $c; ?>;
            $(".add").click(function() {
                count = count + 1;

        $('#here').append('<p> Song Title <input type="text" name="songs['+count+'][title]" value="" /> -- Track number : <input type="text" name="songs['+count+'][track]" value="" /><span class="remove">Remove Track</span></p>' );
        return false;
    });
    $(".remove").live('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
</script>
    </div><?php

    }

    /* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
    function dynamic_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
        // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
        // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
            return;

        // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
        // because save_post can be triggered at other times
        if ( !isset( $_POST['dynamicMeta_noncename'] ) )
            return;

        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['dynamicMeta_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
            return;

        // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data

        $songs = $_POST['songs'];

        update_post_meta($post_id,'songs',$songs);
    }
```

As you can see, 'page' is referring to page where I want to post to. Now when I loop for the results on the page template nothing shows up.

```
     <?php            
        $args = array(
'post_type' => 'page',   
    );  
    $repeat_loop = new WP_Query( $args ); if ( $repeat_loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $repeat_loop->have_posts() ) : $repeat_loop->the_post();
    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'songs', true ); ?>                  
    <?php echo $meta['title']; ?><?php echo $meta['track']; ?>
         <?php endwhile; 
             endif;
                wp_reset_postdata(); 
            ?>
```

I do get results when I use the 'var_dump($posts);'. I just can't get it to display in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `$meta['title']` to `$meta['title'][0]` & the same thing for `$meta['track']` . change it to `$meta['track'][0]`

**UPDATE:**

I looked at the code more deeply and you basically need a foreach loop.
Here's the final code should look like:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page'
);  
$repeat_loop = new WP_Query( $args ); if ( $repeat_loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $repeat_loop->have_posts() ) : $repeat_loop->the_post();
$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'songs', true ); ?>                  

<?php
foreach ($meta as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['title']; ?><?php echo $value['track'];
}
?>
<?php endwhile; 
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! Your approach is a hint in the right direction. I tried it and when I use $meta[0]['title'] (move the order around) I get the first result. But since it is an array I want to loop through all results and display all of them. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Answer edited. This will work for you.

Comment: Haha, looks like our answers have been overlapping. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it thanks to the hint from Abdul! I need to loop through my array so I implemented a simple for loop:

```
    <?php for( $i= 0 ; $i <= 10 ; $i++ ) echo '<p>' .$meta[$i]['title']. '</p>';?>
```

Thanks a lot for the help!